# Wordpress: Counting total number of times tags are used

Tags: php, sql, count, wordpress

I successfully rejigged existing code to count the total number of posts within a specific tag, and then print the sum. I cobbled this together based off of an existing snippet and although it works, I realize it is very inefficient.

Ideally it would be great if I could count the number of posts in all tags, and return the total so I wouldn't have to hardcode `$term_name`.

I know theres a loop there somewhere... This is my first time really dealing with PHP so while this is exciting, it reminds me I have a lot to learn.

```
<?php
$taxonomy = "post_tag"; // can be category, post_tag, or custom taxonomy name

// Using Term Name
$term_name = 'Cookies';
$term = get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy);

$term_name1 = 'Juice';
$term1 = get_term_by('name', $term_name1, $taxonomy);

$term_name2 = 'Milk';
$term2 = get_term_by('name', $term_name2, $taxonomy);

// Fetch the count, sum and print.
echo ($term->count + $term1->count + $term2->count);
?>
```

A little clarification: I want to count the posts under each tag, and then sum them, even if  double counting posts. I'm using tags as a sort of inventory of a post. Lets say we're using tags to identify items in a picture, you could use this to say 20,000 different items tagged.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly are you asking?

Comment: He wants a list of terms and the count. I'm typing an answer now

Comment: Thanks! Apologies if I wasn't clear. Basically I'm trying to count the number of posts attached to each tag, and return the sum. 

If #cookies has 3 posts under that tag, #milk has 2, and #juice has 1, then the output would be 6, since the above tags were used six times.

Really I'm counting the number of posts under each tag, and summing them, even though some posts may be under multiple tags.

Comment: I've revised my answer to incorporate another possible solution based on your latest comment.

Answer (score 2):

Really, first thing you need to do is build a list of terms that are used, then get the counts. Both of these can be done in a single database query.

```
$taxonomy = 'post_tag'; //the post type you want to look up
global $wpdb; //get instance of database connection
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT terms.name,taxonomy.count
        FROM wp_terms AS terms 
        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS taxonomy ON (terms.term_id = taxonomy.term_id)
        WHERE taxonomy = %s;",$taxonomy);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

if ( $results ){
    foreach ( $results as $result ){
        echo('<p>'.$result->name.' has a count of '.$result->count.'</p>');
    }   
}
```

Please note: you should further refine the answer by using $wpdb->prefix instead of hard coding "wp_"...but if this is just for your own use and not for redistribution you don't need to worry about that.

EDIT:

Based on a comment on the original question, an alternate SQL could be:

```
$taxonomy = 'post_tag'; //the post type you want to look up
global $wpdb; //get instance of database connection
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT sum(taxonomy.count)
        FROM wp_terms AS terms 
        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS taxonomy ON (terms.term_id = taxonomy.term_id)
        WHERE taxonomy = %s;",$taxonomy);
$result = $wpdb->get_var($sql);

echo("There are a total of $result tag matches");
```

A note: If you have 2 posts each using 3 different tags, you will get a result of 6 (which is what you wanted in your comment...but not what others might want).

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. I really appreciate your efforts. I keep getting:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /wp-content/plugins/php-code-for-posts/PHPPostCode.php(85) : eval()'d code on line 11`

Comment: I think its `echo("There are a total of $result tag matches);`. I added end quotes and only got" There are a total of tag matches. No numerical value tallying the number of times each tag is used.

Comment: Do you have posts saved to the database? What happens if you run the SQL directly against your database?